# Retornar Datatable Webmethod to Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un webmethod en el cual lleno un objeto `datatable`, el cual tendrá como 300 filas por 20 columnas.

Mi duda es si se puede retornar como `datatable`, lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
        [WebMethod()]
    public static DataTable allValues()
    {

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cad"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA; cnn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = " SELECT TOP 500 * FROM Table1 ";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sqlDA.Fill(dt);
        cnn.Close();

        return dt;
    }
```

Y lo recibo de la siguiente manea, pero no me esta retornando nada.

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Default.aspx/allValues") %>',
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.d + '***');
            },
            error: function (x, y) {
                console.log(x);
            }

        });
```

Pueden decirme si es posible?, o que otro metodo me recomiendan para pasar muchos registros?. Uso Asp.net Webforms.

Gracias.

Comment: Amigo @PolloKulos , tengo una pequeña duda para ver si edito mi pregunta o no. Donde se encuentra tu script de ajax? esta en la misma pagina aspx o en un js aparte? y en que nivel?

Comment: El script de ajax esta en la misma pagina aspx

Comment: corregí la url para que pruebes la solución, me avisas si tienes dudas

Comment: Gracias ya lo cheque pero no me funciono, voy a correguir mi pregunta, vi varios detalles que no vi, por ejemplo retorno una lista pero nunca la lleno, y deseo retornar el datatable.

Comment: Ok, estaré atento para editar la respuesta

Comment: La acabo de actualizar, y el script de ajax, lo puse como el ejemplo que pusiste.

Comment: La verdad no se que es un  [WebMethod()] pero supongo que usted lo que quiere es enviar ese datatable del backend al fronted ? Si eso es correcto lo que necesita es un Api Rest para poder devolver un datatable aunque los datatable no tienen buen performance así que yo le recomendaria un IEnumerable<T>  en luga de un datatable

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, creo que tu `Webmethod` necesita algunas correcciones. Yo lo realicé en VB y paso mas de 2000 filas con 8 columnas, en VB lo declaro como `Public Shared Function`, por lo que equivalente debería ser así en **C#**:

```
 [WebMethod()]
    public static string allValues()
    {

        List<object> results= new List<object>();

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cad"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA; cnn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = " SELECT TOP 500 * FROM Table1 ";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sqlDA.Fill(dt);
        cnn.Close();

        return results;
    }
```

Estuve mucho tiempo investigando para implementar un plugin llamado [datatables JS](http://www.datatables.net) y esta es la única manera de trabajar con objetos del tipo JSON, los parseo los realizo por el lado del cliente.

Pruebalo y me cuentas como te va.

**EDIT**

Te dejo además unas pequeñas correcciones de Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Default.aspx/allValues") %>',
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.d + '***');
            },
            error: function(x,y){
            console.log(x);
            }

        });
```

Las correcciones son con la URL y la data, además agrego la parte del error para que puedas capturarlo en caso que te lance uno.

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a revisar.